# Enabling CORS in firebase Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, cors, fabricjs, firebase-storage

I'm developing an App using Angular 4 and Fabric.Js. As a Backend, I'm using firebase.

I'm having a problem when trying to apply filters to images. Example provided below:

```
filterTest() {
const image = this._canvas.getActiveObject();
image.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
image.applyFilters();
this._canvas.renderAll();
}
```

When I try to execute the mentioned piece of code I keep getting the following error:

> Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at...

I'm saw some workarounds on the web, but no one seems to work for me.

What should I do? Did anyone have the same problem?
Let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: You probably need to enable CORS for your storage bucket. There are instructions in the firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration

Comment: Hello, Sidney. I tried to to this, however I keep getting the same error. Here is my cors.json:
[{
"origin":["*"],
"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
"method": ["GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
"maxAgeSeconds": 3600
}].

Then I ran gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my-bucket-name

Comment: Can you download the image using the Firebase JavaScript SDK? If so, it's probably something to do with canvas.

Comment: Yes. I can add images to my canvas and manipulate then. I can also send HTTP Requests using XMLHttpRequest().

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for an answer for this problem:

My problem was that I was trying to load images from a JSON file using fabric.util.loadImage(), however I was not setting the last parameter to 'anonymous'!